# ANTLR: handle nested line comments

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Usually, (for syntax coloring) I use following ANTLR lines (e.g. for Java or C++ sources) to detect block comments (`/* this is a comment */`):

```
BlockComment
    :
      '/*' BlockCommentChar* '*/'
      -> skip
    ;

fragment BlockCommentChar
    : '*'  ~'/'
    | ~'*'
    ;
```

But in the [V](https://vlang.io/) language block comments are allowed to be nested. I could imagine to somehow increase a counter at a detected `/*` and decrease it on `*/`, but how to do that and how to report everything between the `/* fdksjfldjlf /* fjdsjfkds f */ jfdjf jd */` as one lexer token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
BlockComment
 : '/*' ( BlockComment | '/' ~'*' | ~'/' )*? '*/'
 ;
```

Comment: Could this cause a stack overflow?

Comment: Maybe. Perhaps with an insane amount of successive `/*`. Try it.

Comment: Note that this will also accept `/* /* */` as a block comment because the second `/*` will be matched by two applications of `.` when it can't find a match using the recursion.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Good point @sepp2k, updated my answer.